# How to fix asynchronous code locking when working with asyncpg

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-asyncio, aiohttp, asyncpg

This is the sample code I am using. I wanted to quickly parse the pages and enter the resulting data into the database. However, after adding one line, my code started to run significantly slower. I understand that this is related to the work of the database. But I don't understand how to fix it.

If you have any other suggestions for speeding up this code, I would be grateful for your help.

```
import asyncpg
import asyncio
import aiohttp
from settings import URI, SQL, URLS


class Singleton(type):
    _instances = {}

    def __call__(cls, *args, **kwargs):
        if cls not in cls._instances:
            cls._instances[cls] = super(Singleton, cls).__call__(*args, **kwargs)
        return cls._instances[cls]


class DBManager(metaclass=Singleton):
    """ Class for interacting with Postgres database """

    def __init__(self, dsn) -> None:
        """ The constructor takes the database """
        self.dsn = dsn
        self.pool = None

    async def connect(self):
        self.pool = await asyncpg.create_pool(dsn=self.dsn)


    async def insert_data(self, peson: str, address: str):
        async with self.pool.acquire() as connect:
            return await connect.execute(SQL, type_tx, address)


db = DBManager(URI)


async def check_address(url, session):
    async with session.get(url) as result:
        try:
            result = await result.json()
            person = 'adult' if result['age'] >= 21 else 'child'
            address = result['address']
            await db.insert_data(person, address)
            return print(address, person)
        except Exception as e:
            print(e)


async def bound_fetch(sem, url, session):
    async with sem:
        return await check_address(url, session)


async def main():
    await db.connect()
    urls = [url for i in URLS]
    sem = asyncio.Semaphore(50)
    tasks = []
    async with aiohttp.ClientSession() as session:
        for url in urls:
            task = asyncio.ensure_future(bound_fetch(sem, url, session))
            tasks.append(task)
        responses = asyncio.gather(*tasks)
        await responses

if __name__ == '__main__':
    asyncio.run(main())
```

Comment: How performant is it?

Comment: it is '''await db.insert_data(person, address)''' slows the script a lot

Comment: @axwr It works well without writing to the database

Comment: Yes, await is going to slow the script drastically, but you don't need to await? you can just insert and move on asynchronously rather than synchronously waiting for the call to finish?

Comment: @axwr  Yes, I don't have to wait. I just don't understand how I can add this to the existing asyncio.gather

Answer (score -1):

awaiting for a task to complete is slow. By necessity await will *wait* for a task to complete. When it is not necessary to wait, simply carrying on and not blocking your code is generally preferable.

As you mention, this line: `await db.insert_data(person, address)` is slow. That's because it is awaiting the db.insert. But you are not using the result of this so rather than await you can just omit the await and allow the insert to go ahead asynchronously.

You mention asynchio, the python documentation gives a good overview of this [here](https://docs.python.org/3/library/asyncio-task.html).

Comment: I added create_task instead of await, it didn't help. Could you explain the solution to me more specifically?